# Supress NullPointerExemption Error on starting AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi everyone got this weird error whenever i start android studio
null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.workspace.OCWorkspaceManager.getWorkspace(OCWorkspaceManager.java:12)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.clearAllSymbolDependentCaches(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:381)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.access$400(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:47)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity$7.run(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:241)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity$14$1.run(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:420)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1009)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity$14.run(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:416)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Im trying to figure out whats the cause of it and how to suppress it.

Comment: `NullPointerException` show your code

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yup even when i created a new black project.

Comment: please read https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205399

Comment: @Kaii NPE comes from the NDK support plugin. So disable that and restarted AS.

Comment: @Kaii did you read this link ?

Answer (score 2):

file > settings > plugins

1. disable the plugin: Android NDK Support
2. restart Android Studio

but I do not know why the plugin throw this exception